# Is there an Eclipse project example of a soundboard using only one mediaplayer

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I have been trying to develop an Andriod app of a simple sound board, which will play several long sounds, and only one at a time, not simultaneously.  I can easily do a soundboard that uses repetitive code and many mediaplayers, but that will likely crash many devices due to allocating too many instances of MediaPlayer.  I want to use a map so that I only use one mediaplayer, but after several hours, I’m still having compile problems.  I could also use the App Inventor at MIT, but I don’t think I could upload that to market place without extensive key/signing hacks, so I don’t think that is a good option.

Does anyone know if there a working code example with just a couple of sounds that use just 1 mediaplayer included with the SDK, or available online?  If I could start with just a basic working design, it would save me so much time.

My code looks like the below:

```
public class newBoard extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId; 

@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

*//below line causes an error due to use of "newboard"*

    setContentView(R.layout.newboard); 

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); 
    final Resources res = getResources(); 

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou 
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.button01, R.id.button02, R.id.button03, 
                              R.id.button04, R.id.button05, R.id.button06, 
                              R.id.button07, R.id.button08, R.id.button09, 
                              R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, 
                              R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15, 
                              R.id.button16, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, 
                              R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, 
                              R.id.button21, R.id.button22, R.id.button23, 
                              R.id.button24, R.id.button25 }; 
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.sound01, R.raw.sound02, R.raw.sound03, 
                              R.raw.sound04, R.raw.sound05, R.raw.sound06, 
                              R.raw.sound07, R.raw.sound08, R.raw.sound09, 
                              R.raw.sound10, R.raw.sound11, R.raw.sound12, 
                              R.raw.sound13, R.raw.sound14, R.raw.sound15, 
                              R.raw.sound16, R.raw.sound16, R.raw.sound17, 
                              R.raw.sound18, R.raw.sound19, R.raw.sound20, 
                              R.raw.sound21, R.raw.sound22, R.raw.sound23, 
                              R.raw.sound24, R.raw.sound25 }; 

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset 
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding 
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing. 
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) { 
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i]; 
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]); 
                    player.reset(); 
                    try { 
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
                    try { 
                        player.prepare(); 
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
                    player.start(); 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }; 



    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need 
    //to keep a reference to every button 
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]); 
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton); 
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener); 

    } 



} 

}
```

I have only one error:

newboard cannot be resolved, or is not a field   Type: Java problem

A nice project download that could be used as a foundation would be optimal, if that exists!

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Maytag87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that it can't find your layout XML file.

Does the file **/res/layout/newboard.xml** exist in your Eclipse project? Perhaps the layout is called something else, like **main.xml**, in which case you should use `R.layout.main` in your Java code when you call `setContentView()`.

Comment: I do not have a a layout/newboard.xml, only the layout/main.xml.  Where would you suggest the R.layout.main go in the Java code?  Quick fixes that are deployed when hovering over the newboard want to update the R.java file, but that file is automatically generated and should not be updated manually, so I assume that this proposed change should not be made to the R.java!

Thanks!
Maytag87

Comment: Just tried changing the code from setContentView(R.layout.newboard) to setContentView(R.layout.main) and at least now it compiles!  Thanks!  If others have suggestions about a project sample, I am still all ears!  Thanks!

Comment: And now sound is playing, only one at a time, and with just one Media Player - Awesome, consider this answered!